# Taxonomy term block linked to a view

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, navigation

I have a list of Authors listed as taxonomy terms .
 I also have a view list of Contents named Topics

I need to display the taxonomy terms of Authors in a View block (lets say in the home page).
and then link each term to its related content view page (displayed as List).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a contextual filter for the taxonomy term, and if none is present, to present a summary. Does that get you close to what you are trying to build?

Comment: Thank for your reply , yes i guess you got me right. I'll give it a try also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have 2 views:

**First view: Author's content:**

1. View should be a page.
2. Add all the required field.
3. set path to be like `author/%/content`.
4. Add a contextual filter for the content taxonomy term field (author).

**Second view: Authors list**

1. View should be a block.
2. Add field with term ID (author ID) and mark it to be excluded.
3. Add field with term name (author name).
4. Mark the term name output field to be overridden as a link.
5. Set author name as link text
6. Set `author/[tid]/content` as link path. (You can find correct value for term id in token replacements)

P.S. If you use panels it will be a bit different.

P.P.S. You can use standard `taxonomy/term/%` for the "First view: Author's content" view.

Comment: Thanks for your good explanation, i am afraid i have to bother your as i have been stuck with this issue for months without any solution, and i think what you kindly mentioned seems to be the nearest one to what i am looking for. i am stuck in step five and forward ...... Regards

Comment: can you add what you tried and what is the problem now to do to the task description?

Comment: i could not find  step 5. Set author name as link text and step 6. also.